# How to fix Vue 2 + UIKit autocomplete template?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, getuikit

i have a problem with Vue 2 + UIKit autocomplete.

UIKit autocomplete template is the following code

```
<script type="text/autocomplete" v-pre>
    <ul class="uk-nav uk-nav-autocomplete uk-autocomplete-results">
        {{~items}}
            <li data-value="{{ $item.name }}">
                <a>{{ $item.name }}[{{$item.id}}]</a>
            </li>
        {{/items}}
    </ul>
</script>
```

But Vue 2, seems, removing any tags inside `script` tag.

So, how i can fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is because your `<script>` tag **will not be parsed** if you placed it inside `template`. That's how **vue-loader** work with Single File Components. Template engine in `vue-loader` is only used for translating the template syntax into plain HTML.

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">
     <script type="text/javascript">      
        console.log("This will not be parsed")
     </script>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'hello'
}
</script>
```

So better way to handle this is to use custom component. Luckily [here](https://github.com/BosNaufal/vue-autocomplete) is autocomplete component for Vue.